# Certain numeric data convert to month/year and day

Tags: python, datetime

I have over 20000 lines of csv data file as like this

```
1060A017F57H
2060A017F57H
...
X070A027F57H
...
Y080B032F57H
...
Z9A0A0PPF57H
```

- 1st characters: 1-9 and X,Y,Z are Jan-Sep and Oct, Nov, Dec respectively.
- 2nd characters: 6 to 9 represent 2016 to 2019 and 0 to 5 represent 2020 to 2025 respectively.
- 3rd characters: 1 to 9 represent 1st to 9th, A to Y (except for I, which is not used) represent 10th to 31st of the month respectively.

Do you know which function can convert them back to Month/Year/Date format with python?

thanks a million!

Comment: I haven't seen this format before, but it's kind of neat! I'd suggest writing your own function to handle this - you've described the logic clearly in your question, so you could just write a function that takes 3 characters (or a length-3 string), implements exactly those rules and returns a `datetime.date`.

Comment: "A to Y (except for I, which is not used)" - that's 24 letters though, whereas the 10th-31st inclusive is only 22 days. There must be two more unused letters?

Comment: It seems like it will just be a bunch of `if` statements to determine whether a character is a digit or letter, then translate it to the corresponding month, year, or day. Then you call `datetime.date()` to create that date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to double check your date definition since A-Y less I is more letters than you need but assuming you really meant A-X less I then this should work:

```
import string
from datetime import datetime
def parse_cust(in_str):
    Months='XYZ'
    Days=[x for x in string.ascii_uppercase if x!="I"]
    if in_str[0] in Months:
        mymonth=Months.index(in_str[0])+10
    else:
        mymonth=int(in_str[0])
    if int(in_str[1])>=6:
        myyear=2010+int(in_str[1])
    else:
        myyear=2020+int(in_str[1])
    if in_str[2] in Days:
        myday=Days.index(in_str[2])+10
    else:
        myday=int(in_str[2])
    return datetime(myyear, mymonth, myday).date()
```